# hibernate.cfg.xml path

Tags: hibernate.cfg.xml

I have a java project and I am using hibernate.The thing here is I want to place the hibernate.cfg.xml file outside "src" folder, but when I am configuring this file it is showing FileNotFoundException. If I put it inside src folder its ok. But I want to separate the java src and all config file in separate folder.

```
                               root
                                |____src
                                |____conf
                                      |____mapping
                                             |____(all xml file with hibernate.cfg.xml)
```

SessionFactory _sessionFactory = (new Configuration()).configure("./conf/mapping/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Its showing exception......

Answer (score 1):

Add conf/mapping directory to your `CLASSPATH` and load the configuration file

```
new Configuration().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

or just

```
new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();
```

as this is the standard name.

Regardless there would be no `./` at the beginning of the resource path.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

- include `conf/mapping` in your `project build path`(With Eclipse `properties->javabuild path->source->add Folder`)
- then no need to precise the hibernate config file in your code
  `new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();` is enough

This manipulation is simple and works like a charm.